# Figure title (suptitle()) disappears if you specify figure size in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

Take, for instance, this code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = np.random.random(100)
g = np.random.random(100)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
fig.suptitle('Long Suptitle', fontsize=24)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(f)
plt.title('Very Long Title 1', fontsize=20)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(g)
plt.title('Very Long Title 2', fontsize=20)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.show()
```

Running it shows two subplots with individual titles, but the overall figure title "Long Suptitle" is not visible.

However, if you remove `figsize=(15,15)`, then the overall figure title becomes visible again.

**Is it possible to keep the `suptitle()` text visible while modifying the size of the figure?**

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I can't reproduce your problems (The suptitle is visible and in a reasonable place for me).   What version of matplotlib are you using?  It's possible that this is a bug that's been fixed recently.  Also, a workaround would be to pass in a different `y` position to `suptitle`. That shouldn't be necessary, though.

Comment: Like @JoeKington I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by combining the `plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))` and `suptitle` into one line:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10)).suptitle("mytitle",fontsize=20)
```

(on matplotlib 2.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout = True)
fig.set_figheight(15)
fig.set_figwidth(15)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).